# Python - "Undo" text-wrap

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I need to take a text and remove the \n character, which I believe I've done. The next task is to remove the hyphen from words where it should not appear but to leave the hyphen in compound words where it should appear. For example, 'encyclo-\npedia to 'encyclopedia' and 'long-\nterm' to 'long-term'. The suggestion is to compare it with an original text.

```
with open('C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Comp_Ling_Research_1\BROWN_A1_hypenated.txt', 'rU') as myfile:
data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
```

I have a general idea of what to do but NLP is quite new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first pass would be to keep a set of valid words around and de-hyphenate if your de-hyphenated word is in the set of valid words. Ubuntu has a list of valid words at /usr/share/dict/american-english. An overly simple version might look like:

```
valid_words = set(line.strip() for line in open(valid_words_file))

output = []
for word in open(new_file).read().replace('-\n', '').replace('\n', ' ').split():
    if '-' in word and word.replace('-', '') in valid_words:
        output.append(word.replace('-', ''))
    else:
        output.append(word)
```

You would have to deal with punctuation, capitalization, etc., but that's the idea.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking of how to de-hyphenate. Conceptually, I wrote this down:                                                                                                 #If you have two lists or files,
#For one item in the first list with a hyphen,
#check for the same item in the second list with or without the hyphen.
#If the item in the second list does not have a hyphen then delete the hyphen from the first list.

Comment: Might there be a good reference. If I look for removing hyphens I find the simple method but not how to remove hyphens based on a reference list. It feels like it is a kind of reverse text-wrapper process.

Comment: import re


with open('C:\Users\Paul\BROWN_A1.txt', 'rU') as truefile:
    true_corpus = truefile.read()

true_tokens = true_corpus.split(' ')

with               open('C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Comp_Ling_Research_1\BROWN_A1_hy     penated.txt', 'rU') as myfile:
         my_corpus = myfile.read()

    my_tokens = my_corpus.split(' ')

Comment: Appreciate this very much. A colleague of mine recommended the method below but the one above also is very interesting.

Comment: You need to replace newlines with spaces (except when hyphenated), otherwise you're gluing words together.

Comment: True. Now updated. Also, this is just to convey the idea. One should not use the above code directly.

Comment: Doesn't work. Now you remove all line-final hyphens, plus some hyphens from the middle of the line.

Comment: True, but again, this was just to convey the idea. There are multiple things which will not work with the above code, as stated in the answer itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
import re


with open('C:\Users\Paul\BROWN_A1.txt', 'rU') as truefile:
    true_corpus = truefile.read()

true_tokens = true_corpus.split(' ')

with open('C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\Comp_Ling_Research_1\BROWN_A1_hypenated.txt', 'rU') as myfile:

my_corpus = myfile.read()

my_tokens = my_corpus.split(' ')
```